# Mathematics for rotation in d3.js for 3d charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying implement the rotate on drag functionality in d3 for a 3d chart, for reference  I am using following example from d3 but not getting the maths behind it.
Can anyone please explain me the math for rotation in this example

http://bl.ocks.org/supereggbert/aff58196188816576af0

Comment: Maybe you could ask this at math.se...

Comment: Well you basically have to apply a 3D matrix-rotation on every single point based on how much is has been dragged in x and y on the screen. The Math isn't very easy for this, but if you are interested you can find a lot on the internet about these 3D Transformations. Also I'm not sure how it's done in the example, since I would do it differently^^

Comment: @CoderPi  Most of the example that I found was using projection (geo), but my chart is totally different.
Can you please refer me to some example where I can see some other maths use.

Answer (score -1):

as @coderPi mentioned you have to rotate and project every single point. Think about it like so: Your 3d point (x,y,z) can not be displayed on your screen because it only has x and y. To get the point onto your screen you have to project it. A very common projection is the [orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection). For the rotation you should use a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) (and there are various ones). If you don't want to do this all by your self, I created a decent d3.js [plugin](https://github.com/Niekes/d3-3d).